# Which is correct, bloodsucker or bloodsuckers?

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

In the following sentence, which is correct, bloodsuckers or bloodsucker? Please explain it to me.

> No other insect bloodsucker/bloodsuckers is/are as highly developed as mosquitoes.

Comment: It think the adjectival form works best: _No other **bloodsucking insects** are as highly developed as mosquitoes._

Comment: ... or... *No other bloodsucking insect is as highly developed as the mosquito.*

Answer (score 2):

As both J.R. and JavaLatte mention, "insect bloodsucker" is an awkward expression.  It's better to use the adjective *bloodsucking*:

> No other **bloodsucking insects** are ...
>   No other **bloodsucking insect** is

This answers your actual question is whether it is better to use the singular or the plural: it doesn't matter.  Both are fine, and the difference is a matter of personal style.

> Among insects, no other **bloodsucker is** ...
>   Among insects, no other **bloodsuckers are** ...

Also both of these are fine:

> **The mosquito is** the most efficient bloodsucking insect.
>   **Mosquitoes are** the most efficient bloodsucking insects.

Comment: **insect bloodsucker** would be fine in a context that seeks to differentiate various kinds of bloodsuckers, such as bloodsucking insects, bloodsucking mammals, bloodsucking fish/eels.

Answer (score 1):

In a context where you have differentiated between various kinds of bloodsuckers (insects, mammals, fishes), **insect bloodsucker** is grammatical and idiomatic.

> No other insect bloodsucker is as highly developed as the mosquito.

Outside such a context, however, **bloodsucking insect** would be the expected phrase.

P.S.

We say **no other insect bloodsucker is** if we wish to take  **the mosquito** as the archetypal member of the class and set it head-to-head against the archetypal member of each of the other bloodsucking insect classes, and to say that it is more highly developed than each of them.

We say **no other insect bloodsuckers are** if we wish to set the mosquito as a class containing multiple members and set those members as a group against the members of other bloodsucking insect classes, and to say that mosquitoes as a group are more highly developed than all of the others.

> No other insect bloodsuckers are as highly developed as mosquitoes [as a group].

I prefer the first one, but you can take your pick.